# Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor never grows beyond corePoolSize

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, threadpool

I have configured Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, having in mind 16 threads at least and up to 256 on the need-basis:

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="16"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="256"/>
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="256"/>
</bean>
```

But as I can see from logs, thread pool size never exceeds *corePoolSize*:

```
Thread pool size: 16/256, active count: 16
```

Why is that so? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Maybe there was never the necessity to have more than `corePoolSize` threads.

Comment: Tasks are waiting in the thread pool for as long as 500ms... Feels like there is a good reason to grow beyound.

Comment: Also, if I set *corePoolSize* to 1, issue persists.

Answer (score 10):

Got it:

```
If there are more than corePoolSize but less
than maximumPoolSize threads running,
a new thread will be created only if the queue is full.
```

So the solution is to shrink the queue!